# Google Maps as texture map

Tags: google-maps, 3d, webgl, three.js

Hasn't anybody thought about creating dynamic texture of Google Maps? So for instance, we create a simple plane and apply a texture to it that is going to be an actual map of Google (with all of it properties, like drag, zoom, etc.).

Would be nice to somehow deploy google map to a canvas element, grab it as a map for Object3D texture, hide it and listen to its changes (mousemove, etc.) and update the texture map again as it’s being changed.

Hasn’t anybody implement this already? Or maybe at least somebody has some thoughts on how to do this implementation??? May be some alternative that I don’t know about?

Correct me if I’m wrong, but I think that it would be nice to have Google Maps inside of THREE.js as a plugin or even as a part of library.

Comment: Sounds like you want others to solve your problem.

Comment: Sounds like I'm not sure if what I want to do is reasonable enough)))

Answer (score 0):

I have definitely thought about this and I'm not alone. You should be verrrrry prudent if you choose to do so, however: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

For student-ish projects you may be okay but don't be surprised if your game or real estate company gets a C&D letter in like 2 hours after release  :)

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of answer I was hoping to get. But let's say I’ve purchased Google Map for Business, is it reasonable to do such a thing in terms of performance? I mean, redrawing canvas every frame, generating map and changing the texture – on one hand seems like it’s an expansive calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this has already been done.

> The Google Maps team joined with B-Reel to make the Google Maps Cube
>   Game, where you help a small blue ball navigate the streets of New
>   York, Tokyo, Paris and San Francisco (among others). As you move your
>   mouse the cube rotates and the ball rolls down the streets, bouncing
>   off buildings and making its way towards the goal.
>
> No discussion on WebGL is complete without mentioning Mr. doob's
>   Three.js library at some point, and this is no exception: the Maps
>   Cube game makes use of Three.js for its gorgeous rendering. If you're
>   considering doing some WebGL work in a commercial setting, Three.js is
>   a really good place to start; it's a very nice library that will save
>   you a lot of headaches.

http://www.playmapscube.com/ (requires chrome).